# Rails: Creating a static string class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, class, static, global-variables

I'm new to Rails and I'm trying to understand a basic concept.

I would like to create a class that inclues only static variables of strings, where I can call them from a controller when I want to. I wanted to achieve this by creating a **strings** folder under **app** directory. Later on I've created a class called **String**

```
class Strings
@testString="this is my test string"
end
```

Later on I fail when I try to call it from a controller's **index** (but I don't think the function or the controller would matter. Why I cannot reach it? Do I have to apply **def self.testString** all the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create them as methods or constants:

```
class Strings

  TESTCONST = "this is my test string"

  def self.test_string
   "this is my test string"
  end

end
```

Using them: Strings.test_strings or Strings::TESTCONST

Comment: Thank you so much for the useful answer. So the constanst require to be written in caps?

Comment: It would be more appropriate if `Strings` were a module rather than a class, as you're never going to instantiate it.  I prefer the constants approach personally.

Comment: @Ali Correct, constants are in all upper.

Comment: Technically they only need start with an uppercase character.  All uppercase is just a convention, often with class/module names in camelcase.

Comment: My strings.rb class is located under a directory called 'strings' which is located under app folder. And the methods you mentioned above doesn't work in my application

Comment: Rails has its own way of handling the (auto)loading of files.  If you want a nonstandard directory to be loaded in a Rails project you have to specify that in application.rb.  Look for `config.autoload_paths`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a strings folder under app/models.  One of the classes under app/models will be ErrorMessages.

One way is to use constants.  This is what constants were designed for in ruby.
So file app/models/strings/error_messages.rb would be:

```
class Strings::ErrorMessages
  TEST_STRING = "this is my test string"
end
```

Alternatively, you could have an [cattr_reader](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Class.html#method-i-cattr_reader), where app/models/strings/error_messages.rb would be:

```
class Strings::ErrorMessages
  cattr_reader :test_string

  @test_string = "this is my test string"
end
```

Or you could just have a method return the read only string.

```
class Strings::ErrorMessages
  def self.test_string
    "this is my test string"
  end
end
```

Comment: #2 isn't correct as `attr_reader` defines methods on the instance, and you're assigning an instance variable on the class.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Would you also add how would I be able to call this variable. Like `user=Strings.TEST_STRING` ?

Comment: Answer edited from comments to be called from ErrorMessages.test_string.

Comment: For #1 call as Strings::ErrorMessages.TEST_STRING.  For #2 and #3 call as Strings::ErrorMessages.test_string.